# ISO date field converts automatically while reading in PySpark from MONGO

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a date field from MongoDB collection to PySpark df. My date field has an ISO format when seen in mongo DB but it gets converted into a different type after reading on Spark.

```
 In Mongo the date looks like below

 ISODate("2012-07-14T01:00:00+01:00")

 df =  (sqlContext.read.format("com.xyz.datasource.mongodb").options(host="mongo:XXX",database="foo", collection="bar").load())
 df.show()
```

My date column gets converted like below:

```
{ "$date": 1.62345674343 }
```

I understand this got converted to epoch and I have an UDF which converts to human readable timestamp but on why this happens? Is there a fix which avoids or ignores my UDF (I would like to not apply UDF on columns)?

I have multiple `createdAt` fields which I like to change.

[image: schema]

Answer (score 1):

spark only supports epoch seconds and not milliseconds, sometimes data coming out of mongo has epoch milliseconds. In that case you would divide the epoch milliseconds integer by a thousand.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = sqlContext.read.format(
        "com.xyz.datasource.mongodb"
    ).options(
        host="mongo:XXX",
        database="foo", 
        collection="bar"
    ).load().withColumn(
        'date', 
         col('exposure.knownEmployeesExposed.latestIncidentReport.createdAt').cast('timestamp')
    )
```

Comment: I get null with the column after trying your code

Comment: probably because that field is nested. could you share a snippet of schema where the $date field is? its most likely something like this `'Document.StartedDate.$date'`.

Comment: Added schema pic in the question

Comment: i dont see `$date`, I see `date` under `LatestBadgeActivity.date`, is that the one in question?

Comment: column createdAt is present in few places in schema thats what is getting converted to $date on spark unknowingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226098/discussion-between-jayrythium-and-chetan-vasudevan).